# Closest saying for "If you don't busy yourself doing something constructive, you'll find yourself doing something destructive"

Tags: popular-refrains

In Arabic and Hebrew there is a saying that roughly translates to the title. What is the closest saying in English, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The proverbs ***idle hands are the devil’s workshop***, idle hands are the devil’s tools, and idle hands are the devil’s playground mean that someone who is unoccupied and bored will find mischief; someone who has nothing to do will partake in something that will get him into trouble.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1 <sub>[Grammarist.com](https://grammarist.com/proverb/idle-hands-are-the-devils-workshop-tools-or-playground/)</sub></sup>

Comment: I've always known it as **Satan finds mischief for idle hands**, although the only version I can find online is by the 17th century hymnwriter Isaac Watts - "Satan will find mischief still / For idle hands to do."

Comment: The variant I am familiar with is *The devil finds work for idle hands.* I can’t find a reliable source online however.

Comment: And to complete the round-up of related sayings, [idle hands are the devil's playthings](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/idle+hands+are+the+devil%27s+playthings).